# RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c99 [OR] gives a 403 sub 371

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters, oscommerce

This is a very strange problem.

A customer has an oscommerce website and he has in his Google account many errors with html code 403 for links (url's). But for 100x many others it is going right.

Such a link is e.g. `http://www.xx.com/yyy-500-zzzz-p-9785.html?language=de&osCsid=1e12581c9a1fcae0dbd1ec99cde5334c9`

In .htaccess a redirect is defined : `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c99 [OR]`

==================================

Answer:

c99.php was ever a hackers program etc. so this rule prevents c99 in an url.

Strange is that this customer has only c99 in the session id's in url's but for no other customer I can find this, also not in their databases (session tables) ...

Maybe someone tried to change it in a c99 in an url to find out if c99 is possible or not .. ? ..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's about oscommerce. It maybe about .htaccess rule. To be sure you need to run product_info.php with same arguements. If the code run properly then you must be sure that .htaccess rule created properly.

Comment: Maybe the original link must have one 9, but your site gives one more 9 in addition in where the link shows.

Comment: Thanks Melih for your responce, I shall explain next what happened .. maybe you can explain the difference ...